# Почему ошибка this.state is not function в данном случае? (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs

В данном коде происходит ошибка, в месте const {counter} = this.state

```
   const { render } = ReactDOM
   const { Component } = React

   const data = [
   {img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300',
   id: 0},
    {img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/301',
   id: 1},
    {img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/302',
   id: 3},
    {img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/303',
   id: 4},
   {img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/304',
   id: 5}
    ]

  class Slider extends Component {

    state = {
        data,
        counter: 0
        }

    goForward = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            counter: state.counter+1
        }))
    }

    goBackward = () => {
        this.setState(state => ({
            counter: state.counter-1
        }))
    }


    render() {
        const {counter} = this.state
        (counter===0 || counter===data.length) ? console.log(counter, "yes") : console.log(counter, "no")       
        return <div id='main'>
                <div className = "slider">                  
                <button  onClick={this.goBackward.bind(this)} className='backward'> Back </button>
                <img src={this.state.data[counter].img} /><br/> 
                <button onClick={this.goForward.bind(this)} className='forward'> Forward </button>
                </div>  
    </div>
    }
}  
render(<Slider/>, document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

Comment: Возможно вы имели ввиду `this.setState is not a function`? Попробуйте убрать `.bind(this)` тк они тут не играют роли

Comment: Да иммено это и имел в ввиду. Убрал - не помогло. Вообще не пойму почему так.

Comment: а когда пишу не сокращённое условие if - тогда работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в отсутствии `;`.

Автоподстановка `;` работает в том случае, если транслятор видит оконченный statement

Например

```
const { Component } = React
const data = [
```

В данном случае эти две строки не могут составлять одно выражение, но в случае ниже:

```
const {counter} = this.state
(counter===0 || counter===data.length)
```

Это вполне можно записать как: `const {counter} = this.state(counter===0 || counter===data.length)`

Отсюда видно, что это допустимая синтаксическая конструкция и автодстановка не срабатывает.

В качестве решения нужно либо явно поставить `;`

```
const {counter} = this.state;
```

Либо не использовать тернарный оператор там, где надо использовать обычный `if`.